# Matlab update plot in one GUI based on activity in second GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

In one GUI (viewer) I have an image that shows a 2D slice through a 3D image cube. A toolbar button opens a second GUI (z-profile) that plots a 2D graph showing the z-profile of one pixel in the image cube. What I want is to be able to update this plot dynamically when a different pixel is clicked in the original viewer GUI. I've looked in to linkdata but I'm not sure if that can be used to link across two GUIs. Is there a simple way to do this *without* re-creating the second GUI each time a new pixel is clicked and feeding in the new input location?

Comment: Using `linkdata` of Matlab might work too, but I have no experience there. It seems you can connect data and figure updates and therefore would work if you have something like a "z-profile variable" defined, then linked to GUI 2 and then upon click on GUI 1 change the content of this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely doing it without recreating the second GUI every time.

Without knowing your specific code I would say that you should store a reference to the second GUI in the first GUI, then in a callback for clicking a pixel in the first GUI, change data in the second GUI via the stored reference (e.g. figure handle). You can store arbitrary data in a figure, for example by using function [guidata](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html). A bit of code.

```
...
figure2 = figure();
figure1 = figure('WindowButtonDownFcn',@myCallback);
guidata(figure1, figure2);
...
function myCallback(obj,eventdata)
figure2 = guidata(obj);
...
```

Even easier but a bit more error-prone would be to use global variables for storing the references.